# Autowired annotation issue in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I am getting this error in Spring boot

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppHomeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myAppUserRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.repository.MyAppUsersListRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.repository.MyAppUsersListRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Please help me to resolve this issue.

package com.myapp.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.myapp.model.User;

public interface MyAppUsersListRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}

```
package com.myapp.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="MyAppUsersList")
public class User {
    @Column(name="username")
    private String userNameA;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String emailIdA;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private String passwordA;
    
    public User(String userName,String password,String email)
    {
        this.userNameA=userName;
        this.passwordA=password;
        this.emailIdA=email;
    }

    public String getUserNameA() {

        return userNameA;
    }

    public void setUserNameA(String userName) {
        this.userNameA = userName;
    }
    
    

    public String getPasswordA() {
        return passwordA;
    }

    public void setPasswordA(String pswd) {
        this.passwordA = pswd;
    }
    

public String getEmailIdA() {
    return emailIdA;
}

public void setEmailIdA(String emailIdA) {
    this.emailIdA = emailIdA;
}
    
}


@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080   ")
@RestController
public class MyAppHomeController {
    // Output File path to save Registered Users

    static boolean MethodExecutedOrNot = false;
    
    @Autowired
    MyAppUsersListRepository myAppUserRepository;
    
    
    @PostMapping(value="/storeRegistrationDataForH2")
    public ResponseEntity<User> storeRegistrationDataForH2(@RequestBody User userObj)
    {
      try
      {
         User user=myAppUserRepository.save(new User(userObj.getUserNameA(),userObj.getPasswordA(),userObj.getEmailIdA()));
         return new ResponseEntity<>(user,HttpStatus.CREATED);
      }
      catch(Exception exception)
      {
          loggerObj.log(Level.FATAL,"error in user registration in h2 database(using log)");
          return new ResponseEntity<>(null,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      }
    }

@Repository
public interface MyAppUsersListRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext   =SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    
    String[] beans=appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    for(String obj:beans)
    {
        System.out.println("ApplicationContextObject:"+obj);
    }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide your codes

Comment: Code added. Please check now.

Comment: You added code for the entity. Not relevant here. The error is about other class: com.myapp.repository.MyAppUsersListRepository Another relevant class is the main application class. Please share those classes inclusive package definitions.

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

please try to add **@Repository** annotation for annotate that is a Bean for Spring IOC container.

```
@Repository
public interface MyAppUsersListRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```